# CSRF checking with simpleJWT and DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm starting to use django and I'm lost in the request verification system. I find it difficult to grasp the intricacies of authentication methods.

I am using JWT authentication with restframework_simplejwt to authenticate the user.

Before using the JWT, I had the CSRF checks but it seems to me that I no longer have them since I defined this authentication system.

Here are my settings and my view, built with DRF's ApiView.

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

**view.py**

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MakePredictionView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication,]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, UserPermissionSpeedX]
    throttle_classes = [UserThrottleSpeedX,]
    serializer_class = MakePredictionSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()
        
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            profil = SpeedX(
                player_name=serializer.data.get('player_name'),
                maturite_indice=serializer.data.get('maturite_indice'),
                resultat_vitesse_30m=serializer.data.get('resultat_vitesse_30m'),
                club=serializer.data.get('club'),
                categorie=serializer.data.get('categorie')
            )
            profil.save()
            return Response(SpeedxSerializer(profil).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

If I replace **JWTAuthentification** by **SessionAuthentification** for example, it asks me for the CSRF token. But, If I add **SessionAuthentification with JWTAuthentication** in authentication_class, it no longer asks me for CSRF, and the authentication is done with JWT, without checking the CSRF token. Is this normal? is this risky?

I also tested these parameters but same issue

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'
    ),
}
```

```
class MakePredictionView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, UserPermissionSpeedX]
    throttle_classes = [UserThrottleSpeedX,]
    serializer_class = MakePredictionSerializer
```

I can't quite understand WHEN the CSRF token is checked? and why is it not checked when JWTAuthentication is enabled?

I am developing the application locally for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seesion Authentication and JWT authentication both are used for user authentication but the differenc is that:

**Session authentication**

it's server-side session management to keep track of a user's login state. When a user logs in, the server creates a session object containing the user's session ID, which is stored in a cookie. when the user requests, the server uses this session ID to retrieve the session object and authenticate the user.

**JWT authentication:**

JWT method used JSon web token to authenticate the user. when the use login the JWT create JSON web token against the user that store in a cokkie or local storage. when the user request, the client send the token that contain additional information of that use and authenticate the user and verify that user.

the main advantage is, JWT authentication is more flexible than session authentication.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precisions, I understand better.
Is CSRF protection with the JWT so secure? If the token is stored on the client side, isn't there a risk of a CSRF attack if additional verification is not performed?

Comment: JWT is much secure than CSRF, because JWT can only be symmetrically signed by a shared secret using the HMAC algorithm. and yes there's a risk of a CSRF attack

Comment: Thanks for the details. In this case, what should I implement to avoid CSRF attacks? JWT is stored in localStorage currently. I read that it prevents CSRF attacks but not XSS.

Comment: if you really want to implent JWT then I will suggest you to see my repo here this is a link https://github.com/tanveer-ahmad74/Dummy its quite simple and easy if you find any difficulty related to this you can ask me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that if you are using simple JWT or any form of JWT authentication you use custom way to ensure that before you perform any action validate CSRF. Before you call any POST,PUT<DELETE request you call below method with your request object.

Also, It's not a good idea to put JWT in localStorage you should use same site Cookie

Here is how you can do it:

```
def ensure_csrf(request):
"""
This function ensure csrf is validated manually. This is used for class based views
:param request:
:return:
"""
request.csrf_processing_done = False
reason = CsrfViewMiddleware(request).process_view(request, None, (), {})
if reason is not None:
    return reason
```